# What is the purpose of /usr/libexec?

Tags: fhs

Executables are stored in `/usr/libexec` on Unix-like systems. [The FHS says](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s07.html) (section `4.7. /usr/libexec : Binaries run by other programs (optional)"`:

> `/usr/libexec` includes internal binaries that are not intended to be executed directly by users or shell scripts. Applications may use a single subdirectory under `/usr/libexec`.

On macOS, `rootless-init` a program called by `launchd` immediately after booting, is stored in `/usr/libexec`.

Why would it be stored in `/usr/libexec` when it is a standalone executable that could be stored in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`? `init` and other programs not called directly by shell scripts are also stored in folders like `[/usr]/{bin,sbin}`.

Answer (score 66):

It's a question of supportability - platform providers have learned from years of experience that if you put binaries in `PATH` by default, people *will* come to depend on them being there, and *will* come to depend on the specific arguments and options they support.

By contrast, if something is put in `/usr/libexec/` it's a clear indication that it's considered an internal implementation detail, and calling it directly as an end user isn't officially supported.

You may still decide to access those binaries directly anyway, you just won't get any support or sympathy from the platform provider if a future upgrade breaks the private interfaces you're using.

Answer (score 15):

OS X doesn't follow the [FHS standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s07.html). It has its own filesystem hierarchy (similar to FreeBSD filesystem hierarchy). The man page [`hier`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/7/hier/) states:

> `libexec/`- system daemons & system utilities (executed by other programs)

Comment: Then it seems that `/usr/libexec/java_home` is definitely in the wrong place in OSX.

Answer (score 11):

`libexec` is meant for system daemons and system utilities executed by other programs. That is, the binaries put in this namespaced directory are meant for the consumption of other programs, and are not intended to be executed directly by users.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's newer than `init` - the idea is, like it said, to have executables (so they shouldn't be in `/usr/lib`) that you would never expect to have in anybody's `$PATH`.